Nginx config file for different application
I have nginx.conf
server {
  listen        8081;
  server_name   _;

  location = / {
    root      /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files /index.html =404;
  }

  location / {
    root      /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index     index.html index.htm;
    try_files /portal$uri /static$uri =404;
  }

  location = /edit {
    root      /usr/share/nginx/html/editor;
    try_files /index.html =404;
  }

  location ~* /edit/(.*) {
    root      /usr/share/nginx/html/editor;
    try_files /$1 =404;
  }
}

My stack:
react
react-router-dom (HashRouter)
nginx
nx (NxWebpackPlugin)
I have editor application with HashRouter and when I try opening app I see home page, but when I navigate to other page I have 404 error.
URLs
http://example.com/edit - work
http://example.com/edit/#/page1 - not work
I know that this is because of the 2 locations /edit and /edit/, but I don’t know how to properly configure the build or nginx
Could you please advise how to properly configure nginx.conf in this case? Maybe you have other suggestions?

Make the third location match /edit and /edit/. E.g. location ~* ^/edit/?

@Richard Smith and what write in try_files? /index.html? or whar?

The contents of the location block are already perfect, because you want both the /edit and /edit/ URLs to return /index.html.
